# Is there an iPad connection kit to import RAW images from a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, raw, canon-5d-mark-ii, ipad

Is there a way to connect a Canon 5d MK2 to an iPad for copying the contents of the CF card especially in Raw format?

Comment: You planning on using your iPad as an onsite backup solution?  I hope you got the big one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with my iPad and the camera connection kit using a USB CF reader and the USB connector on the iPad. I found it was much faster using the reader than the camera. I was even able to upload some of the better pictures to my photo hosting account using a 3rd party app. I will say though to not use it as the only tool to decide if the color is image is worth keeping. On mine at least the color rendering is not as good for RAW as Adobe Camera Raw.

Comment: Also be aware that when accessing RAW images stored on the ipad via a 3rd party app (to upload for instance) depending on how the developer wrote the app the jpgs it gets from your RAW files may only be a max of 1600x1600px, not the full resolution.  In fact, the vast majority of apps will only get the 1600x1600px version so don't delete the original RAW files from your device...

Answer (score 3):

Using [Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A#overview) you can connect your camera and your iPad. Since yor camera has a CF card you cannot use the SD card reader, you have to use the USB connection.

According to [this review](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/reviews/entry/apple-ipad-camera-connection-kit/) it may not work:

> The iPad had no issue bringing in a
>   huge group of 10-Megapixel photos from
>   a Canon Powershot S90 camera, but
>   repeatedly choked mid-stream when
>   trying to import a bunch of
>   21-Megapixel JPEG images from the
>   Canon 5D Mark II. Some of the 5D Mark
>   II pictures transferred without an
>   issue, but the import process
>   typically stopped abruptly after fewer
>   than 10 images—an apparent bug.

Comment: And to address the question of RAW images, yes you can put RAW images from your 5DII onto the iPad and it'll even create jpgs from them to view in your camera roll.

Comment: Yup.  I've done this no problems with my 5DmkII / iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Camera Connection Kit to import JPG, PNG, RAW, NEF, and RW2 photos with no problem.  I use Photo Shack Pro to access the files I import and organize them into albums and libraries with titles and comments. It also gives me access to the photo's embedded camera metadata, lens, location, etc.  The CCK is a much better way to go than iTunes, mainly because I don't have to lug my laptop along.